# Resource-constrained project scheduling

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy, cython

I'm trying to implement an algorithm for a resource-constrained project scheduling problem. I have several resources, `resource constraints` and all of this is in integer time domain. With my class `ResourceUtilization` I want to assure that resource constraints are not violated in all time. Key element of my class is array `utilization` with size `(num_resources, max_makespan)`. I add an activity  of given resource `demands` to `ResourceUtilization` from `start_time` to `finish_time`. I also need to remove that activity at some point. Most called method `is_free()` checks whether I can add an activity to a time interval.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython

DTYPE = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t

cdef class ResourceUtilization:
    cdef DTYPE_t[:, :] res_constraints
    cdef DTYPE_t[:, :] utilization
    cdef DTYPE_t max_makespan
    cdef DTYPE_t num_resources

    def __init__(self, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] res_constraints, DTYPE_t num_resources, DTYPE_t max_makespan):
        self.res_constraints = res_constraints
        self.num_resources = num_resources
        self.max_makespan = max_makespan
        self.utilization = np.zeros([self.num_resources, max_makespan], dtype=DTYPE)

    def add(self, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] demands, DTYPE_t start_time, DTYPE_t finish_time):
        """
        Add demands from interval <start_time, finish times) to resources.
        Expand utilization if needed.
        """
        cdef DTYPE_t[:, :] copy_util
        if finish_time > self.max_makespan:
            self.extend_makespan(finish_time)
        copy_util = self.utilization[:, start_time:finish_time] + demands
        self.utilization[:, start_time:finish_time] = copy_util

    def remove(self, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] demands, DTYPE_t start_time, DTYPE_t finish_time):
        """
        Remove demands from interval <start_time, finish_time) from utilization.
        """
        cdef DTYPE_t[:, :] copy_util
        copy_util = self.utilization[:, start_time:finish_time] - demands
        self.utilization[:, start_time:finish_time] = copy_util

    def extend_makespan(self, DTYPE_t minimal_extend_time):
        """
        Extend length of utilization for at least minimal_extend_time
        """
        cdef DTYPE_t difference
        cdef DTYPE_t[:, :] extenstion
        if minimal_extend_time > self.max_makespan:
            difference = self.max_makespan * np.floor(minimal_extend_time / self.max_makespan)
            extension = np.zeros([self.num_resources, difference], dtype=DTYPE)
            self.utilization = np.hstack((self.utilization, extension))
            self.max_makespan += difference

    def get(self, DTYPE_t resource, DTYPE_t time):
        """
        Get utilization of resource in time.
        """
        return self.utilization[resource][time]

    def get_capacity(self, DTYPE_t resource, DTYPE_t time):
        """
        Get residual capacity of resource in time
        """
        return self.res_constraints[resource] - self.get(resource, time)

    def is_free(self, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] demands, DTYPE_t start_time, DTYPE_t finish_time):
        """
        Check whether we can add demands to interval <start_time, finish_time)
        """
        return np.all(self.utilization[:, start_time:finish_time] + demands <= self.res_constraints)
```

Here you can see example of usage:

```
def test_ru():
    res_constraints = np.array([[4, 6, 2, 3]], dtype=np.int).T
    num_resources = 4
    max_makespan = 16
    ru = ResourceUtilization(res_constraints, num_resources, max_makespan)
    demands = np.array([[4, 3, 0, 1]], dtype=np.int).T
    assert ru.is_free(demands, 0, 4)
    ru.add(demands, 0, 4)
    assert not ru.is_free(demands, 0, 4)
    ru.remove(demands, 0, 4)
```

I'm trying to test my class performance in whole algorithm, because `ResourceUtilization.is_free()` is one of the most called function and therefore bottleneck. When I run this code it is as fast as pure Python/NumPy solution. I was expecting that it will run much faster. I tried `cython -a resource_utilization.pyx` and it still contains a lot python call (you can find it [here](http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xsebek02/resource_utilization.html)). I'm trying to use Cython for the fist time so I'm not sure at all whether I use it well. Do you have any ideas how to speed up my class?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the generated code it's no wonder that the solution is
the same as regular NumPy/Python since it's not taking advantage of
Cython in any way.  There are still calls to the same NumPy functions
and the loop/`np.all` call isn't inlined, so there's no opportunity for
a speed-up.

Except for algorithmic changes, one option here is to create a loop
which does the same thing as the combination of `np.all` plus slicing
and test if that's faster.  If so, then there'd also be alternatives
with parallel processing/threading to make the test faster.  Then again,
the arrays need to be quite large for that to offset the increased
complexity.

I'm having a bit of trouble with the intended shapes of the
vectors/matrixes; the idea would be to have something like this (but the
code doesn't quite work so far!, as the `test` variable should probably
be a vector instead?):

```python
def is_free(self, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] demands, DTYPE_t start_time, DTYPE_t finish_time):
    """
    Check whether we can add demands to interval <start_time, finish_time)
    """
    # return np.all(self.utilization[:, start_time:finish_time] + demands <= self.res_constraints)

    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] test
    test = self.res_constraints - demands

    for i in range(start_time, finish_time):
        if np.all(self.utilization[:, i] > test):
            return False
        # OR inline this test, iterate through the vector directly
        for j in range(self.utilization.shape[0]):
            if self.utilization[j, i] > test[j]):
                return False

    return True
```

Also, `get_capacity` with the settings from `test_ru` throws an
exception relating to the shapes confusion:

```python
>>> ru.get_capacity(0, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "resource_ru.pyx", line 61, in resource_ru.ResourceUtilization.get_capacity (...)
    return self.res_constraints[resource] - self.get(resource, time)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'resource_ru._memoryviewslice' and 'int'
```